# download an entire directory in a phoneGap (iOS) from a server?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

i Am struggling for a about 1.5 days trying to find a solution without success.
i want to download an entire directory that web content (images, html, js and css) to the persistent storage in an iOS PhoneGap app. I tried compressing the files into a single file and was able to download it to the persistent storage but i was not able to extract it. to extract the file i've tried multiple things none of them worked for me:

zip.js
archive.js
and phonegap-plugin-ExtractZip https://github.com/fiscal-cliff/phonegap-plugin-ExtractZip

does anyone have an example "unzip" function that i can use. or is there a better way to transfer a whole directory from a server to a phoneGap app?

(i am using cordova-3-3-0)

thanks in advance,

Comment: why you want to do that? curious

Comment: because i want the user of the app to be able to fetch a list of new "web content"(html5, css, js) and choose things that he wants to download, the app should be able to run the content (html5, css, js) offline after the user downloaded it from my server.
do you have another suggestion.

Comment: you need to use restful in able to download web content

Comment: it is possible download the web Content via RESTful services, but it can contains a lot of files and images/videos that can go up to 200mb, thats why i want to download a compressed folder. the compression and download of the .zip files to the permanent storage of works but the extraction doesn't. do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: sure you can. you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop app that integrate with restful service. You can download sample code from my github account.

https://github.com/datomnurdin/service-finder-mobile